# Common initialisation from mutually exclusive constructors

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a simple base class with mutually exclusive constructors for different scenarios.

```
abstract class ExampleA
{
    protected ExampleA(int intParam)
    {

    }

    protected ExampleA(string stringParam)
    {

    }
}
```

My sub-classes for the most part need only implement a single constructor that extends a single base constructor. All is well. However, I have a special case where a sub class must be initialised outside of my standard workflow.

```
class ExampleB : ExampleA
{
    private readonly int myMagicInt;

    public ExampleB(ExampleC instanceC) 
        : base(instanceC.someString)
    {
        // Derive readonly values here.
    }

    public ExampleB(ExampleD instanceD) 
        : base(instanceD.someInt)
    {
        // Derive readonly values here.
    }
}
```

This is my first encounter with a scenario where I cannot appropriately chain my constructors; doing so in this circumstance would introduce more overhead than initialising my readonly values in more than one place.

Short of re-architecture, is there an approach that can be used handle these scenarios cleanly, or is it something that is simply not expressible in C# without additional layers of complexity or overhead?

Although I have considered the following solutions, none of these are more appealing to me than a re-architecture:

- Nullable parameters on the base, so a common constructor could be called.
- Using another method to initialise the ReadOnly values with 'out' parameters.
- Changing Readonly members to private settable members.

Answer (score 1):

Well, can't you do this? (do note that I am inferring quite a lot from your code and could be misinterpreting your actual scenario):

```
class ExampleB : ExampleA
{
    private readonly int myMagicInt;

    public ExampleB(ExampleC instanceC) 
        : this(GetEquivalentIntFromString(instanceC.someString))
    {
    }

    public ExampleB(ExampleD instanceD) 
        : base(instanceD.someInt)
    {
        // Derive readonly values here.
    }

    private static int GetEquivalentIntFromString(string s)
    { //whatever }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing an int into the second constructor as instanceD here?
My code example is a simplification, and this approach seems to rely on being able to derive instanceD from instanceC or visa versa. If this was possible, I could add a third private constructor which accepts an int, and implement this pattern.